# jQuery search list by class

Tags: jquery, class, sorting

I am trying to write a jQuery function that will search through lists on a page that have urls that contain several classes. I want the function to use the word typed into a search box to match list items that contain a class that matches what was typed, and show only those list items.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="internships">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
<button class="sort button">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="internships">
 <ul class="descriptions">
  <li><a class="item biology bioinformatics pre dentistry medicine nursing pharmacy" href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/oral-pathology-medicine-and-radiology">Oral Pathology and Medicine &amp; Radiology</a></li>
  <li><a class="item biology biomedical engineering biotechnology chemistry neuroscience biochemistry" href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-medicine-angela-bruzzaniti">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a></li>
  <li><a class="item biology health sciences pre medicine dentistry" href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-rachel-menegaz">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a></li>
  <li><a class="item biology biotechnology chemistry health sciences pre dentistry medicine nursing pharmacy" href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-richard-gregory">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

*Note: This is only one section, there are a few more lists on the page but they have to be broken into sections because of the framework the university that I work for is using.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.sort').click(function() {

    $('.search').keyup( function() {
        //Declare what is typed in the search box as a variable to use
       var value = this.value;
       $("#dom_element").text(value);
       //if the items with class .item contain the class that matches what is typed into the search box, show them, else hide them.
       if( $('.item').hasClass) {
           ('value').show();
       }
       else {
           $('.item').hide();

       }

    });

});
```

So, if a user types nursing in the search box, I want only the list items that have anchor tags with nursing in the class to show up. I've tried a few different methods that are out there(list.js being one) but I could not find any that are able to sort by classes. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything, and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches on the class of those `a` elements? Also, what do you need to sort the elements by?

Comment: Note that a data attribute might be better suited for that list, rather than classes.

Comment: Rory, I don't think they need to be exact, I need to sort the elements by relevance to what is typed in the search box (The classes on the links are majors that are related to the internship, I want the students to be able to find applications relevant by their major)

Comment: Great, thank you guys. I will be working through your answers for now and get back to you afterwards. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll recommend a couple general improvements here and then answer your question.

First, you should put your search box inside of a form. This gives you more capabilities forward-thinking, for example if someone doesn't have JS enabled you can have them actually submit the form box and sort results as they're displayed (using e.g. PHP). Additionally you can play with the URL a bit more naturally this way and let visitors use things like `example.com?search=biology` to e.g. bookmark searches.

I'd also put your class names on the `li` elements instead of the `a` elements. This is more for styling needs and general organization - if you CSS style the `li` element in any way and only hide the inner `a`, the `li` will likely still be visible.

If you must have classes on the `a` elements, in my code below swap `$(this).hasClass(val)` with `$(this).find('a').hasClass(val)`.

**Onto your actual question.**

`hasClass` accepts a parameter to check, you don't seem to be sending anything so it won't find the ones you're looking for. Fix with:

```
if ( $('.item').hasClass(value) ) {
```

The click, keyup setup could be simply keyup, but I'd recommend (again) making the search an actual form, then run your search function on form submit. As such:

```
<form class="search-form" action="" method="get">
  <input name="search" type="text" />
</form>

$('.search-form').submit( function(e) {
  // Do search/ filter
});
```

**All together now:**

```
<form class="search-form" action="" method="post">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
  <button class="sort button">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="internships">
  <ul class="descriptions">
    <li class="item biology bioinformatics pre dentistry medicine nursing pharmacy">
      <a href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/oral-pathology-medicine-and-radiology">Oral Pathology and Medicine &amp; Radiology</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item biology biomedical engineering biotechnology chemistry neuroscience biochemistry">
      <a href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-medicine-angela-bruzzaniti">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item biology health sciences pre medicine dentistry">
      <a href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-rachel-menegaz">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item biology biotechnology chemistry health sciences pre dentistry medicine nursing pharmacy">
      <a href="/apply/internship-manager/school-of-dentistry/dentistry-richard-gregory">Biomedical and Applied Sciences</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


$('.search-form').submit( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var val = $("input.search").val(),
      elems = $(".descriptions li");

  $.each(elems, function() {

    if ( $(this).hasClass(val) )
      $(this).show();
    else
      $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/0xnfyanL/

Comment: Great thank you all so much, I went with this solution and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is a bit funky with a key event inside a click event. I'd recommend removing the `keyup` and just filter the `li` based on the search value like so

```
$('.sort').click(function() {
  var classes=$('.search').val().split(' ');
  $('.item').show();
  $('.item:not(.'+classes.join('.')+')').hide();
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3rzjbax/1/)